# Show Ant Design Table's data Vertically

Tags: reactjs, datatables, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to create a table using the Ant Design in React JS. where the rows set the table titles rather than the columns. In other words, I'm trying to transpose the default table.

by default ant-design tables are shown like this:

```
 First Name | Last Name | Date of Birth | Address
 ----------------------------------------------------
 Fred       | Smith     | 1/1/1980      | 123 Main St
 ----------------------------------------------------
 James      | Williams  | 6/30/1985     | 456 Main St
```

But instead, I'd like to transpose the table so it looks as follows:

```
First Name     | Fred        | James
-------------------------------------------
Last Name      | Smith       | Williams
-------------------------------------------
Date of Birth  | 1/1/1980    | 6/30/185
-------------------------------------------
Address        | 123 Main St | 456 Main St
```

Any guidance is welcomed!

Comment: Looks like there is still no such option for AntD Table and [this answer is actual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804756/17871977)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think antd provide an api to transpose the table. But if your table is simple and you don't want features like sorting, filtering..etc, then you can take a look at antd Description https://ant.design/components/descriptions/ or you can use List https://ant.design/components/list/#header

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32193892)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `<Descriptions> </Descriptions>`. Offical document link is: [Descriptions Component](https://ant.design/components/descriptions/)